# What does this line mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Reading [**this article,**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/will-voters-reward-democrats-for-their-stimulus-bill-151116280.html) there is a line,

> **Critics on the right say the bill’s enormous price tag, which many argue is inflated by items on the progressive wish list, will turn off moderate voters who worry about Democrats ramming through a left-wing agenda.** Republican opposition to the bill may even become an asset if the country struggles to escape the pandemic or the surge in spending results in runaway inflation, others say. Some on the left fear that concessions made to satisfy moderate Democrats could temper support for the party among progressive voters.

Would the bold part mean that the stimulus package includes so much progressively-leaning items that the it might scare away moderate democrats?

Thank you for taking time.

Comment: Yes, it does mean what you think.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I disagree. :The "moderate voters" that these "critics on the right" are talking about are not the moderate Democrats. Those critics would be delighted to have the moderate Democrats on their side - which did not happen. The bill passed with unanimous Democratic support. I think the quote is expressing a wish for that to happen.

Comment: @EthanBolker: I don't really understand what you're saying. So far as I can see, the cited text consistently distinguishes "voters" (the public) from "Democrats" (politicians). And what it says is simply that right-wingers think the stimulus package is too left-wing, whereas (some) left-wingers think it's too right-wing. And so far as I'm concerned, the only reason it includes the word ***some*** is because the writer is a left-winger himself (of the ***far-left*** persuasion, which he calls "progressive" to avoid scaring away "moderate **readers**").

Comment: Ah right - I think I see now. You're saying OP should have written *it might scare away moderate **people who normally vote for** democrats*. I don't suppose that minor detail is relevant, but if so I agree.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The quote isn't the OP's, it's from something they read. I think it's subtle politics-speak, therefore hard for an English language learner to feel the nuances. I think the meaning of the text in context is depends on the fact that the stimulus package did _not_ scare away those Democrats.

Comment: Yes - I think it's a very skilfully worded piece of "persuasive writing". The politics of which I completely disagree with, which *may* make it easier for me to notice that I'm being "persuaded" - but also may make me a bit sloppy when it comes to9 decyphering the exact meaning.

Comment: (What ***I*** think is the writer is effectively putting up a smokescreen to divert attention from the - to me, somewhat surprising *and* disappointing - fact that apparently ***not a single Republican*** voted in support of the package. This at a time when the entire nation is dangerously polarised, so there's a desperate need for politicians on both sides to try and find at least *some* points of agreement, and thereby "lead by example".)